# How do I read modal logic's countermodels?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I'm really new to Modal Logic (and logic in general, actually) and currently playing with a tree proof generator just to see how some stuff work, but I can't read the countermodels that the algorithm gives me when my proposition is invalid. I (kinda) understand the concept of possible words and so on, I just can't read it there. Can someone explain to me?

Example: [https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%E2%96%A1(a%E2%86%92b)%20|=%20%C2%AC%E2%97%87(a%E2%86%92%C2%ACb)](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%E2%96%A1(a%E2%86%92b)%20%7C=%20%C2%AC%E2%97%87(a%E2%86%92%C2%ACb))

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Comment: @cigien Sorry, didn't know. I put it back up.

Comment: @plshalp Thank you for putting it back up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it gives the set of worlds. Then it lists the propositional variables, and next to them the set of worlds at which they hold. Then they give $R$, the accessibility relation between the worlds. So, this one says, there is one world, $w_0,$ and $a$ and $b$ are both false there, and then that the accessibility relation has $w_0$ accessible from itself.

Since $a$ and $b$ are false there, $a\to b$ holds at $w_0,$ as does $a\to \lnot b,$ and since $w_0$ is accessible from itself and the only thing accessible from itself, $\square(a\to b)$ and $\lozenge(a\to\lnot b)$ both hold at the only world $w_0.$ So it follows that this is a counter model to $\square (a\to b)\models \lnot\lozenge(a\to\lnot b)$.